# Does warnings affect the performance of my flash application?

Tags: flash, performance, actionscript, warnings, flexbuilder

I have a lot of the following warnings:

- Duplicate variable definition.
- variable 'elem' has no type declaration.
- Illogical comparison with null.  Variables of type Boolean cannot be null.

Will they affect the performance of my flash application? Will they affect the compiling time?

/Andreas

Comment: Performance:No, Correctness:Maybe, but they sure need attention! especially "Illogical comparison with null"

Comment: No.. But you should probably take a look at them and get rid of them either way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't directly affect your program performance (at least in terms of speed/cpu/memory use), but by the sounds of it the warnings you've listed will definitely stop your program doing what it is intended to do.

It's definitely worth cleaning up what you can though - adding a type declaration is easy (even if it's just `elem : *`, although you probably want to be more specific if you can), and comparing for null means that your boolean test won't work correctly (sounds like you're thinking of Java-style Booleans, where the object is a wrapper around a primitive, and so can be null -- in AS, Boolean always has a value)